# How do you get data from form in Vue template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I just want to send POST request to my server using fetch but since I'm kinda new to Vuejs I'm not sure how to get data from data. 
my pug code is like this below

```
<template lang="pug">
.wrapper
  .container
    h1 CNTRL
    form(v-on:submit.prevent='onSubmit').form
      input(type='text', placeholder='Username', v-model='id')
      input(type='password', placeholder='Password', v-model='password')
      button#login-button(type='submit') Login
</template>
```

This Is what I wrote on script section but It doesn't work. I don't know what's wrong with this.

```
export default {
    data () {
        id: '',
        password: ''
    },
    created () {
      // Set $route values that are not preset during unit testing
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing') {
        this.$route = {
          name: 'landing-page',
          path: '/landing-page'
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            fetch('/signup', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    id: this.id,
                    password: this.password
                })
            })
        }
    },

  }
```

Comment: Whats happening when you dump this.id and this.password before calling fetch. Do you see the entered values? Otherwise can you show the HTML?

Comment: Are you exporting a class? Should it be export default class? Is data suppose to be a function? is created suppose to be a function? Looks quite different from how other vue instances are created. Shouldn't you be creating a new vue instance instead: `export default new Vue({})`?

Comment: Are you getting any erorrs?

Comment: `data` inside a component should be a `function`, not a plane object. Besides, tell us what errors do you get. `Doesn't work` doesn't help.